# Fill struts2 select tag with javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, struts2

Is it possible to fill the Struts 2 select tag with javascript array on load?

I have a code

```jsp
<s:select id="attrStpSel" name="attrStpSel" headerKey="-1"
          headerValue="Select" list="${attributeActions}"
          labelposition="left" onchange="displaySelectAction()"
          cssStyle="width: 300px;" />
```

This is the script in the page.

```jsp
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var attributeActions = [ 'Add', 'Update', 'Search' ];
    });
</script>
```

Since it is a hard coded values, I don't want them to be populated from action. with the above code the javascript variable `attributeActions` is not being picked up.

What should be the ideal way to populate the static list into the Struts 2 select tag?

Comment: Why javascript, and why struts tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an inline list with `#{}`:

```jsp
<s:select name = "attrStpSel" 
     headerKey = "-1"
   headerValue = "Select" 
          list = "#{'Add','Update','Search'}" />
```

You can also create an inline map with the same notation:

```jsp
<s:select name = "attrStpSel" 
     headerKey = "-1"
   headerValue = "Select" 
          list = "#{'0':'Add' , '1':'Update' , '2':'Search'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts select tag renders ordinary html `select`. It also adds additional tags, attributes, CSS to the generated html because it's UI tag. You can read more about [select](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html)  tag.

> Render an HTML input tag of type select.

If you want to populate this select tag with javascript you can do something like this

```
$(function() {
    var attributeActions = [ 'Add', 'Update', 'Search' ];
    var $select = $('#attrStpSel');
    $select.find('option').remove();
    $('<option>').val("-1").text("Select").appendTo($select);
    $.each(attributeActions, function(index, value) {
      $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo($select);
    });
});
```