# Struts2 Change a list content from JSP for an action in session

Tags: jsp, session, scope, struts2

An action in session scope has a List X of String containing 5 elements.
In the JSP, there's a functionnality which allows user to add or remove elements from this list X.

The problem is that the removed elements are not removed from the list in the session action on form submission. 
But, if i update the content of the elements, the jsp list has the updates. If i add elements, the jsp has the new elements.

ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().getContext() --> don't see the removed elements
ActionContext.getContext().getParameters() --> can see all elements (even if removed). Look like 'X[0] , X[1], X[2] , ...'

Need help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--removing something on the client side doesn't do anything on the server side, you need to rebuild or modify the list based on the form submission.

Comment: Example: In the action a list of 5 elements 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' is initialized. In the JSP all elements are displayed then user remove element 'c'. Now user sends form submission, only 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e' are sent in the form. But, in the action the 'c' element is still present it's not removed.  If the scope of the action is 'request' there's no problem ('c' is removed). But with the scope 'session' the 'c' element is still there with its content.

Comment: It won’t magically disappear unless you remove it.

Comment: I know, but how to do this ? I think about two ways : 1) set to null the value of the element to be removed 'c' in javascript, send it in the form with the null value and the other values,  and then in the action search for any null elements then remove them.  Or 2) using the params interceptor : removing any values in the valueStack where name starts with 'X[' , before setting parameters from form but is seems dirty.

Comment: Either rebuild the list from the form submission or remove elements not present in the submission, like I said earlier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812205/573032